# Interaction versus split sample

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, inference, interaction, binary-data

Let's say I want to do a linear regression with data on the dependent variable `Y`, a dummy variable `D` and one more binary variable, `G`, denoting belongingness to some group `A` (or `B` if it's `0`).

I want to compare the effect of `D` on `Y` between the groups. I could:

(1) Set up a regression model with `D`, `G`, and `D*G` as explanatory variables

(2) Set up two different regression models, one for each group, and with `D` as the explanatory variable.

**Question 1**

If I want to go with the first option above. Is the specification correct? More specifically: Should I add the interaction variable `D*(1-G)`? Can I skip `G`?

**Question 2**

Which is the best option? My intuitive feeling is that I should go with the first option if I can argue that both groups belong to the same underlying population, and choose the second option if I believe that the two groups belong to different underlying populations. I'm not sure if this is wrong/correct, and if I am missing something other than this.